# Laravel - BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\User::getAuthIdentifierName()

Tags: laravel, authentication

I know this question has been asked many times, but none of the answers given helped. In part, because most of the answers say to do what is already done. Every page gives the error: "BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\User::getAuthIdentifierName()".

Here's what happened. Authentication was working good. Then I did a fresh migration:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

After that, the error comes up.

Here's my App/User Model code:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use jeremykenedy\LaravelRoles\Traits\HasRoleAndPermission;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
// class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoleAndPermission;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

I've tried running `php artisan ui vue --auth` and putting in "yes" the all the overwrite questions, but that did not work.

Any assistance as to what else could be causing this would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** Just FYI the only thing I changed to re-migrate was a couple Seeding files.

Comment: So it seems cookies saved in my browser caused the error. I cleared the cache and now it's loading fine.

Comment: Mark the question as resolved

Comment: But then there's the issue of every browser that accessed the site before is having the same issue. Is there a way to clear a user's cookies for the site programmatically?